# How to calculate the closeness centrality of the node in a directed graph step by step?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, graph, networkx

I have a simple directed network graph object `G`. It is created as follows:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

nodes = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]

G.add_nodes_from(nodes)

G.add_edges_from([("A","B"), ("A","C"),
                  ("B","D"), ("B", "E"),
                  ("C", "F"), ("C", "G"), ("C","H")])

pos = {"A":(10, 10),
      "B":(7.5, 7.5), "C":(12.5, 7.5),
      "D":(6, 6), "E":(9, 6),
      "F":(11, 6), "G":(14, 6), "H":(17, 6)}

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = pos, arrows = True,
                 node_shape = "s", node_color = "white")
```

It looks as shown below. A is the root node. B and C are intermediate nodes. And D, E, F, G, and H are leaves.
[image]

Closeness centrality is calculated as the average of the shortest path length from the node to every other node in the network according to this [source](https://dl1.cuni.cz/pluginfile.php/730998/mod_resource/content/0/Jennifer%20Golbeck-Analyzing%20the%20Social%20Web-Morgan%20Kaufmann%20(%20%202013).pdf) page 27.

I can calculate the closeness centrality of this graph using `nx.closeness_centrality(G)`. And I get the following results:

```
{'A': 0.0,
 'B': 0.14285714285714285,
 'C': 0.14285714285714285,
 'D': 0.19047619047619047,
 'E': 0.19047619047619047,
 'F': 0.19047619047619047,
 'G': 0.19047619047619047,
 'H': 0.19047619047619047}
```

The closeness centrality of A is 0 because it is the root node. The closeness centrality of B and C are 1/7 because the distance from A is 1 and from all other nodes is 0. I think it is calculated as (1+0+0+0+0+0+0)/7. However, I cannot understand why the closeness centrality of other nodes is same. Their value is equivalent to 2/10.5. I am not sure how it is calculated.

Is it possible to show how the closeness centrality is calculated step by step rather than getting it directly from `nx.closeness_centrality(G)`?

Comment: In a graph with more than one connected component, `nx.closeness_centrality(G)` calculates the closeness centralities using the Wasserman and Faust improved formula. (see `help(nx.closeness_centrality)`). It is not clear if "connected" means "strongly connected" or "weakly connected." Your graph is not strongly connected. `nx.closeness_centrality(G)` and `nx.closeness_centrality(G,wf_improved=False)` give different results.